# Mac: number of bytes transmitted over interface

Tags: macos, networking, network-adapter, monitoring

On linux, I'm used to typing `ifconfig` and looking for the line with "RX bytes" and "TX bytes" in it to find out how many bytes have been received and transmitted over a particular interface since boot. The line looks like this:

```
      RX bytes:106951129 (101.9 MB)  TX bytes:1577761831 (1.4 GB)
```

I tried running the same command in a terminal on a Mac (OS X, version 10.4.11) but didn't see this data anywhere. How do I get the same information from a Mac?

**Edit**: This is a test server, meant to simulate a typical out-of-the-box Mac install. So I need to avoid installing any programs if I can. A command-line tool would be ideal.

Answer (score 12):

```
netstat -ib
```

seems to do the trick. Thanks to nik for pointing in the right direction. (Putting the result in a new answer so as not to make future readers dig through comments.)

Comment: From user [Girish](https://superuser.com/users/971230/girish): Just building on this answer, `netstat -ib -I en0` would return the stats for a specific interface.

Answer (score 0):

The *easiest* way I know of seeing bytes in/out over an interface (w/o command line) is with [MenuMeters](http://www.ragingmenace.com/software/menumeters/). You can see all that info right on the top bar so it's always visually accessible.

Comment: This mac is a test server so I don't want to install stuff on it if I can avoid it. I need a command-line tool if at all possible. I'll edit the question to say that.

Comment: Whoops. Sorry, I thought this was for a desktop. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try [`ifconfig -a`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/ifconfig.8.html).
But, I suspect there is a better command for the OSX.
It is discouraged to use the `ifconfig` command in OSX like its used in Linux.

check [`networksetup`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/networksetup.8.html) or [`netstat`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/netstat.1.html).

Comment: ifconfig -a doesn't have the number of bytes (or if it does, I can't find it). networksetup doesn't seem to be available, and netstat (and netstat -a) doesn't seem to have it either.

Comment: I expected "`netstat -i en0`" kind of command for the first Ethernet interface.